# jQuery DOM object referenced children

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

In an attempt to create cleaner code, I am trying to write event handler functions that are aware of where they get called from. I am not sure if what I'm trying to do is not the correct way to do things, or if the underlying nesting of divs within tables that the page is made up of is causing problems.

The goal of the below table/js is to take data from the attributes of the image tag, and populate them into the input elements within the parent/ancestor table.

Table Structure:

```
<table id="formbody">

    <tr><td>
    <table class="form_item_wrapper" id="form_item_1">

        <tr><td><div id="search_results"><img class="event_handler" foo="bar" /></div></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Foo: <input id="event_input" name="foo_input_1"></td></tr>
   </table>

    <table class="form_item_wrapper" id="form_item_1">
        <tr><td>
            <div id="search_results"><img class="event_handler" foo="baz" /></div>
        </td></tr>

     <tr><td>Foo: <input id="event_input" name="foo_input2"></td></tr>
    </table>

     </td></tr>


</table>
```

Each of the **.form_item_wrapper** tables has a section that can dynamically populate the list of **.event_handler** images. Once the $.get() that retrieves the entries populates the data, it attaches the handlers to the images to fire populate_shipment_details(event) onclick. That part works fine, the events fire correctly and I can read my custom attributes from the image elements. This is the function that gets called when one of the images is clicked:

```
function populate_shipment_details(event){

var form_wrapper = $(event.target).closest('.form_item_wrapper');

var foo_input = $(form_wrapper).children('#event_input');

    foo_input.val($(event.target).attr('foo'));

}
```

The problem I am having is that while form_wrapper properly resolves to the table containing the image that was clicked on, Firebug is showing that foo_input is showing up "emtpy" in Firebug. For whatever reason, I cannot create variables that point to children within the form_wrapper. Ideally, this is the code that I want to write... but doesn't work.

```
$(form_wrapper).children("#event_input").val($(event.target).attr('foo'));
```

Comment: From the code I can see you are nesting tables inside of tables. In general I think you should only use tables to present tables of data. Tags make it possible for search engines to pull headers and paragraphs and definitions from a webpage. It is misleading to use tables for any other purpose.

Comment: Never say never but never nest tables!

Comment: The structure of the code is NOT my design or decision... I'm just trying to change the least ammount of it possible while implementing some new functionality. I actually have considered re-writing most of the structure as a solution to my problems but I'm worried about unnecessary time spent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('img.event_handler').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.event_input').val($(this).attr('foo'));
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/HMJcy/

Note: I had to replace the id attribute with the class attribute on the INPUT elements, since ID's have to be unique on the page, and you have multiple INPUT's.

Comment: Do you think the root of my issue might be using multiple IDs?

Comment: Hi, Šime beat me to it. "children()" only finds IMMEDIATE (first-level) elements, which for a TABLE would be TBODY elements etc. As the answer says, change "children" to "find". Regards

Comment: @Dirty You can use multiple ID's. You can have as many ID's as you want on your page. However, all ID's have to be unique. You cannot have two ID attributes with the same value. Since you have multiple INPUT elements on your page, give them a class instead of an ID.

Comment: Today I learned... $().children() != $().find(). You guys are SO awesome thank you very much. Switching those functions worked perfectly.

Comment: P.S. if you have something like `var elem = $('#id')`, then later just do `var xyz = elem.find('tr')`, not `var xyz = $(elem).find('tr')`.